# Installing Etcher and Octopi: Unable to to Unzip and Install either of these programs?

Tags: software-installation

So I have received my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ in the mail.  Plug it in and hook it up.  Everything works awesome up until this point...I would like to mention that I have been a Windows user my whole entire life up until this point.

I don't know if this matters or not.  So I follow the instructions and try to open these Applications that I downloaded from the internet no problem.

I then proceed to firstly install the balenaEtcher onto the device by trying to open it with the "double click and a wizard will pop up" method.  This has not worked thus far.  Don't know what I doing or not doing.  I have dabbled with using the XArchiver saying for it to extract to a certain place, which I have placed both of these programs into my Documents folder at this stage.

Do I have to initiate, save, or otherwise use this computer with the command prompt to install Etcher which I need to install Octopi?

Any help would be much appreciated thank you.

Comment: are you trying to install Etcher on to the pi? because, there is no Etcher released for the pi

Comment: try win32Imager1.0 instead.

Comment: You need to download "Etcher for Windows (x86|x64) (Installer)". After downloading, double-click on the resulting file. Do not try to use any other version.

Comment: Oh my gosh.  I was so very lost and now I finally moved over this hump.....thank you all for your input and I feel very well received.                                                                       I installed Etcher on Windows and unzipped Octopi..on Windows, then formatted the SD card.....from Windows, then proceeded to "Etch" the card with the image....on Windows, then modified the Network file from Notepad ++ ......on Windows. Currently waiting on a print to come out before attaching it and setting it up to my printer.  Thank you all for making this possible and keep the help coming

Answer (score 1):

There is no etcher release for pi. If you want to flash the memory with OS you need a windows or another raspbian activated raspberry pi. Then try this command(if you are using a linux)

```
  sudo dd if (path to image) of (path to device)
```

I this way ou can make a flashable image.